# Does sqlite "insert or replace" work with AUTOINCREMENT primary key?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a database in which i have created one table with name "SectionDetails".
In this table i have set "id" as a primary key with `AUTOINCREMENT`  property.And i am inserting my data into this table.

However, i came to the scenario where i need to check if record i am inserting is already present or not(if record is present then replace it with same values or skip it,And if record is not present then insert new one ).

But when i tried to insert record with same column values, it increases the primary key and insert the same row again instead of replacing.

So, my question is-
**Does sqlite "insert or replace" works with AUTOINCREMENT primary key?**

I am using following query:

```
insert or replace into SectionDetails(Name,Month,Title,Url)values('Deepak',"August","None","www.dd619.com")
```

here column "id" is not appearing because its a primary key with `AUTOINCREMENT` property.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer: no it does not.

The "insert or replace" only works well when you also specify the primary key. With the autoincrement in a setup that you describe, this cannot work.

Probably the quickest way to do that is by creating a custom insert/update method for your use case.

Answer (score 21):

You will need to add some unique constraints to your other columns to make this work and even then you will have your IDs change.

`insert or replace` is really an `insert` with `on conflict replace` conflict resolution strategy. That is, when the insert would violate some constraint, all conflicting rows are first deleted and the insert takes place only then. The `autoincrement` mechanism will then generate a new ID value for you.

For more information: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html