# Android SQLite can't find column that exists

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am creating a table and using insert or replace sql in local database android but it giving me **error** :

*

> **table employeeTable has no column named activationCode (code 1): , while compiling: insert or replace into
>   employeeTable(activationCode,userName,userType,lastSeen)VALUES
>   ('6131313313' , 'testingcheck' , 'Employer' , 'Tue Oct 27 10:04:36
>   GMT+05:30 2015');**

*

My creating table code :

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE " + EMPLOYEE_TABLE + "(" + COMMON_ID_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + ACTIVATION_CODE_COLUMN + "TEXT ," + USER_NAME_COLUMN + "TEXT ," + USER_TYPE_COLUMN + "TEXT,"+LAST_SEE_COLUMN + "Text);";

    db.execSQL(sql);

}
```

My insert or replace code :

```
public void insertEmployeeDetails(String activationCode1 , String userName , String userType , String lastSeen) {
    String sql1 = "insert or replace into " + EMPLOYEE_TABLE + "(" + ACTIVATION_CODE_COLUMN + " , " + USER_NAME_COLUMN + " , " +
USER_TYPE_COLUMN +" , "+  LAST_SEE_COLUMN + ")" + "VALUES ('" +activationCode1 +"' , '" + userName + "' , '" + userType + "' , '"+ lastSeen + "');";

    getWritableDatabase().execSQL(sql1);
}
```

and callback code:

```
myDbHelper.insertEmployeeDetails(employerConstants.activationCode,employerConstants.userName,
                employerConstants.userType , employerConstants.lastSeenon);
```

**Column activation code exists but not able to figure out what causing a problem ?**

Comment: uninstall the app and install it again :)

Comment: @Amy why? show us your table structure?

Comment: @DegenSharew: what u mean by table structure ?

Comment: @young_08 Are you sure your table is getting created without any issue? Asking because you create table query should contain space between `column_name` and it's `datatype` which i don't see in the code posted..

Comment: @Droidwala : i am not sure . Thats why i am struggling . I see it fine but could a very minor mistake to figure out .

Comment: @young_08 i guess that's where issue lies...just put space between column names and datatypes like `ACTIVATION_CODE_COLUMN + "<space> TEXT ," ` and similarly for others in your create sql..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following code for insert data.

```
dataBase = getWritableDatabase();
cValues = new ContentValues();
cValues.put(ACTIVATION_CODE_COLUMN, activationCode1);
cValues.put(USER_NAME_COLUMN, userName);
cValues.put(USER_TYPE_COLUMN, userType);
cValues.put( LAST_SEE_COLUMN, lastSeen);
dataBase.insert(EMPLOYEE_TABLE, null, cValues);
dataBase.close();
```

Also your create query contain error

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE " + EMPLOYEE_TABLE + "(" + COMMON_ID_COLUMN + "  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + ACTIVATION_CODE_COLUMN + " TEXT, " + USER_NAME_COLUMN + " TEXT , " + USER_TYPE_COLUMN + " TEXT, "+LAST_SEE_COLUMN + " Text);";
```

Copy above query and replace with your query
Feel free for comment

Comment: what is the error in create query i pasted ? it probably might be minor one that's why not able to figure out . Please help me to learn it . Thanx

Comment: i replaced mine create query with urs , but still giving the same error ):

Comment: Create your query in this format   CREATE_TABLE1 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE1_NAME + "(" + KEY_ID
    + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, " + KEY_DATE
    + " TEXT, " + KEY_CATEGORY + " TEXT, " + KEY_TEST_SCORE
    + " TEXT, " + KEY_STATUS + " TEXT " + ")";

Comment: @young_08 After correcting the table creation code, you have to uninstall and reinstall your app

Comment: Welcome Keep in touch

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue is in your create query..Try this SQL Query for Create Table

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE " + EMPLOYEE_TABLE + " (" 
        + COMMON_ID_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + ACTIVATION_CODE_COLUMN + " TEXT, " 
        + USER_NAME_COLUMN + " TEXT, " 
        + USER_TYPE_COLUMN + " TEXT, "
        + LAST_SEE_COLUMN + " TEXT);";
```

Then Uninstall and Install the app.. It should work.

Comment: @young_08 After correcting the table creation code, you have to uninstall and reinstall your app

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have proper spaces in the query also, You can fetch the entire data from your emulator and can check what is wrong, I had the same issue then I searched and was able to export the database from my emulator after which I came to know that my field name was not correct due to spacing in the query, I was using genymotion. I can paste the procedure for exporting the data from emulator if you need it.

Comment: Please , that would be great help . Thanx !

Comment: Are you using genymotion or default AVD

Comment: Hi I posted the procedure here. Please check

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33386096/exporting-sqlite-from-genymotion-and-display-contents-in-browser

Answer (score -1):

make your sqliteHelperClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper.

example

```
public SqliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int VERSION = 1;
    public static final String NAME = "your db name";

    public SqliteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, NAME, null, VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // your db creates here
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // your db upgrade here
        // ex) drop & create
    }

}
```

with this helper class,
if you need db upgrade, just change `Version` values + 1

i hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: i am already using it . i have only posted the command code but my sqlite file looks like same . So , this is not an issue . Thanx

Comment: try this `String sql1 = "insert or replace into " + EMPLOYEE_TABLE + "(" + USER_NAME_COLUMN + " , " +
                USER_TYPE_COLUMN +" , "+  LAST_SEE_COLUMN + ")" + "VALUES (" + userName + "' , '" + userType + "' , '"+ lastSeen + "') WHERE " + ACTIVATION_CODE_COLUMN + " ='" +  activationCode1 +"'";`

Comment: activation_code has `autoincrement`, use it under `where`

Comment: As per my knowledge : Insert syntax doesn't support WHERE syntax . Its clearly a Syntax error .

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18152319/4372988) says `insert or replace` doen't support autoincremented primary key. With `where`, I'm sorry about wrong syntax.

Comment: Yes , i think this is what creating an issue . But how to resolve it ? Any help?

Comment: separate function `insert` and `update`. like this `if (activationCode1.equals("") { // insert } else { // update // }`