# How to use single 'INSERT OR REPLACE' for both create and update?

Tags: sql, react-native, sqlite, replace

I am trying to `INSERT OR REPLACE` for both updates. This works if I pass `r_id` to the query but I want to replace only if `r_id` is passed, or insert if `r_id` is empty. When I do this I'm getting a type mismatch error. `r_id` is the primary key, an integer.

```
 INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ${tableNames[1].name} (r_id,r_from_ac_type_id,r_to_ac_type_id,r_date,r_amount,r_note) values` +
      recordItems
        .map(
          i =>
            `('${i.r_id}','${i.r_from_ac_type_id}','${i.r_to_ac_type_id}', '${i.r_date}','${i.r_amount}','${i.r_note}')`,
        )
        .join(',')
```

Comment: since notes are typically user supplied you have at least here a sql injection vulnerability: `'${i.r_note}'`. Put a `'` in your note and see if it crashes. There is probably something like `sql.execute('[..] VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)', [i.r_id, r.r_from_ac_type_id,...])` which takes parameters from an array and binds them to `?` in the supplied order in your query without risk of injection. And why not simply use an if/else depending in the existence if `i.r_id` and then use either insert or update manually? (assuming you don't know an id unless the item exists)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UPSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html). Example from that page:

```
INSERT INTO vocabulary(word) VALUES('jovial')
    ON CONFLICT(word) DO UPDATE SET count=count+1;
```

UPSERT is a budget version of MERGE, from my understanding sqlite does not yet
support MERGE.

Off topic, but be careful when injecting values into sql queries. If possible use prepared statements instead.

Answer (score -1):

Your answer in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152051/does-sqlite-insert-or-replace-work-with-autoincrement-primary-key).

You must use `autoincrement` mechanism will then generate a new ID value.

Comment: This does not work in SQLite.

Comment: Sorry, your answer in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152051/does-sqlite-insert-or-replace-work-with-autoincrement-primary-key)